# MIPS functions and variables in stack

Tags: mips

I have come in contact with MIPS-32, and I came with the question if a variable, for example $t0 declared having the value in one function can be altered by another and how this does have to do with stack, this is, the location of the variable in memory. Everything that I am talking is in assembly language. And more, I would like some examples concerning this use, this is, a function altering or not, a variable value of another function, and how this variable "survive" or not in terms of if the variable is given as a copy or a reference.

(I hope we can create an environment where conceptual question like that above can be explored more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$t0` declared having the value in one function can be altered by another

`$t0` is known as a call-clobbered register.  It is no different than the other registers as far as the hardware is concerned — being call clobbered vs. call preserved is an aspect of software convention, call the calling convention, which is a subset of an Application Binary Interface (ABI).

The calling convention, when followed, allows a function, `F`, to call another function, `G`, knowing only `G`'s signature — name, parameters & their types, return type.  The function, `F`, would not have to also be changed if `G` changes, as long as both follow the convention.

Call clobbered doesn't mean it has to be clobbered, though, and when writing your own code you can use it any way you like (unless your coursework says to follow the MIPS32 calling convention, of course).

By the convention, a call-clobbered register can be used without worry: all you have to do use it is put a value into it!

Call preserved registers can also be used, if desired, but they should be presumed to be already in use by some caller (maybe not the immediate caller, but some distant caller), the values they contain must be restored before exiting the function back to return to its caller.  This is, of course, only possible by saving the original value before repurposing the register for a new use.

The two sets of register (call clobbered/preserved) serve two common use cases, namely cheap temporary storage and long term variables.  The former requires no effort to preserve/restore, while the latter both does require this effort, though gives us registers that will survive a function call, which is useful, for example, when a loop has a function call.

The stack comes into play when we need to first preserve, then restore call-preserved registers.  If we want to use call-preserved registers for some reason, then we need to preserve their original values in order to restore them later.  The most reasonable way to do that is to save them in the stack.  In order to do that we allocate some space from the stack.

To allocate some local memory, the stack pointer is decremented to reserve a function some space.  Since the stack pointer, upon return to caller, must have the same value, this space is necessarily deallocated upon return.  Hence the stack is great for local storage.  Original values of preserved registers must be also restored upon return to caller and so using local storage is appropriate.

https://www.dyncall.org/docs/manual/manualse11.html — search for section "MIPS32".

Let's also make the distinction between variables, a logical concept, and storage, a physical concept.

In high level language, variables are named and have scopes (limited lifetimes).  In machine code, we have physical hardware (storage) resources of registers and memory; these simply exist: they have no concept of lifetime.  In and of themselves these hardware resources are not variables, but places that we can use to hold variables for their lifetime/scope.

As assembly language programmers, we keep a mental (or even written) map of our logical variables to physical resources.  The compiler does the same, knowing the scope/lifetime of program variables and creating that "mental" map of variables to machine code storage.  Variables that have overlapping lifetimes cannot share the same hardware resource, of course, but when a variable is out of scope, its (mapped-to) physical resource can be reused for another purpose.

Logical variables can also move around to different physical resources.  A logical variable that is a parameter, may be passed in a CPU register, e.g. `$a0`, but then be moved into an `$s` register or into a (stack) memory location.  Such is the business of machine code.

To allocate some hardware storage to a high level language (or pseudo code) variable, we simply initialize the storage!  Hardware resources are necessarily constantly being repurposed to hold a different logical variable.

See also:

[How a recursive function works in MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60687721/how-a-recursive-function-works-in-mips/60688088#60688088) — for discussion on variable analysis.

[Mips/assembly language exponentiation recursivley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62665644/mips-assembly-language-exponentiation-recursivley/62667103#62667103)

[What's the difference between caller-saved and callee-saved in RISC-V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64211181/whats-the-difference-between-caller-saved-and-callee-saved-in-risc-v/64211564#64211564)